# Having trouble using Firebase v3 to host my React sample

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am new to hosting React apps on Firebase, so any help would be appreciated. I've already followed the instructions on the new v3 documentations at Firebase.com, but I am unsure which assets/files to place into my public directory. I felt the documentation was quite vague in this regard.

Here is my Firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and my directory structure is below:

```
Name of App
  -build
  -css
  -node_modules
  -public
  -scripts
.firebaserc
database.rules.json
firebase.json
gulpfile.js
index.html
package.json
README.md
```

I've already tried copying the entire contents of the parent directory into the public folder to no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you make your question more specific please? It's not clear what you're problem is.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I basically don't know how to get my react app hosted with firebase v3 and which files to include into the public directory. I talked with the support at firebase and they said dump everything into public directory to no avail.

This is my index.html for ref: http://imgur.com/a/NGgtE

For example all I want is a list of all the files i need to include/not include. Should I include .json files? My gulpfile.js? I figured I need at bare minimum my css and scripts directories along with index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically after messing around for a few hours I found out the solution. Since gulp minifies everything I needed to just push the main.js minified file under build along with the minified CSS folder into the public directory, and now everything works. Case closed.